# Considerations for a RDBMS-agnostic transaction replication subsystem

Tags: postgresql, transactions, replication, rdbms, conflict

I am working on a RDBMS-agnostic (primarily via ODBC to start, though my personal preferred RDBMS is going to be PostgreSQL) transaction replicator for guaranteeing data in two databases is consistent.

This would be in similar vein to [TIBCO Rendezvous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TIBCO_Rendezvous), but not targeted at Oracle, and (likely) non-commercial.

I have considered alternatives such as using a simple [message queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_queue), but if users/processes in two locales update the same object at the same time (or before a transaction can replicate), you are still left with the issue of authority and "who's right".

What are primary considerations to keep in mind, especially concerning the high potential for conflicts in the environment?

Comment: So let me get this straight. You want **database-agnostic synchronous (=consistent) multi-master replication**? Sounds like a pipe dream. It's hard enough to implement synchronous multi-master replication inside the database engine and achieve positive scalability, even with man-years to spend on research. To do it in a database-agnostic way on SQL level will probably have so much overhead that it's not useful for production databases.

Comment: @intgr - that's pretty much it. TIBCO Rendezvous managed to do it for Oracle. There are other systems for other platforms (I know of a proprietary replacement for Rendezvous architected more-or-less by a single guy and implemented by a small team over the course of a couple years; currently it's aimed at Oracle, though it was built to be extensible for other platforms). I'm looking at doing the same thing, but in a FLOSS project

Comment: From all the descriptions I've read about TIBCO Rendezvous, it seems to be just a messaging system/bus like ZeroMQ or AMQP (there's even pg_amqp for Postgres). If I'm not mistaken, it knows nothing about databases, much less synchronity or consistency (well, you can send messages from Oracle DB procedures, but that's about it). If someone built replication around that, then it's probably heavily application-specific and they manage consistency manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some solutions out there, but I have no idea how big the gap between reality and the marketing advertising actually is.

- http://symmetricds.codehaus.org/
- http://www.continuent.com/solutions/tungsten-replicator
  (update: 2015-03-13: does not seem to support Postgres any longer)